# Looking for planetary position calculation

Tags: solar-system, planet

In [Hindu astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology), for creating horoscopes (birth charts), I am looking for calculations of [planetary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology#Grahas_.E2.80.93_planets) [positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology#R.C4.81.C5.9Bi_.E2.80.93_zodiacal_signs). So, how could I calculate planetary positions according to given date, time and place?

Comment: http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons can also be useful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because astrology is not astronomy

Comment: Deducing the position of planetary bodies on specific days is fundamentally Astronomy, even if the OP intends to use the resulting data for astrology.

Comment: You might want to be more specific.  Are you looking for a text on the equations?  A program that can spit out the positions?  A program to make a star chart? A programming library where you can make your own?

Answer (score 3):

If you're only interested in the positions, you'll probably be best off just using a program instead of diving into celestial mechanics. Depending on what you exactly want with "planetary position", here are three different approaches to finding a planet's position at a given time:

1. *Stellarium* is a free program to visually solve for the position of a planet, and it gives some precise data for the positions of the planets too, but it needs to be installed and run on your computer so it won't be the quickest way to find the position.
2. If you're looking to get a planet's coordinates on ecliptic and/or equatorial planes, you can let [this](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224748262) web app do the calculations for you for a given time.
3. Also, a quick Google search came up with [this](http://www.currentplanetarypositions.com/cgi-bin/calculate_planets.cgi) web app meant for working with zodiacs.